# MessageListener not listening to messages in Oracle Queue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, advanced-queuing

I've Oracle Advanced Queue implemented & I'm writing a listener program. Below is my sample:

```
package com.myprog;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.jms.ExceptionListener;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory;
import oracle.jms.AQjmsSession;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class abc implements MessageListener, ExceptionListener {
private static String queueUserName = "admin";
private static String queueName = "my_queue";

// Initialize the logger
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(abc.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String METHOD_NAME  = "main()";

    abc a = new abc();              

      Queue queue;
      try {
       QueueConnection QCon = getConnection();  
       Session session = QCon.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
       QCon.start();

       queue = ((AQjmsSession) session).getQueue(queueUserName, queueName);
       MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);       

       consumer.setMessageListener(a);
       QCon.setExceptionListener(a);

       consumer.close();
       session.close();
       QCon.close();
      } catch (JMSException e) {  
       e.printStackTrace();
      }         

}

public static QueueConnection getConnection() {
  String hostname = "myhost";
  String oracle_sid = "mysid";
  int portno = 1521;
  String userName = "myapp";
  String password = "pwd";
  String driver = "thin";
  QueueConnectionFactory QFac = null;
  QueueConnection QCon = null;
  try {
   // get connection factory , not going through JNDI here
   QFac = AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory(hostname, oracle_sid, portno,driver);

   // create connection
   QCon = QFac.createQueueConnection(userName, password);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return QCon;
}

@Override
public void onException(JMSException e) {
    log.error(e);       
}

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
     TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) message;

     try {
         String m = msg.getText();
         System.out.println("m="+m);
         log.info("MESSAGE RECEIVED " + m);
     } catch (JMSException e) {
        log.error(e); 
     }
}
```

}

Please note that this program is a standalone program which will keep running & listening to messages in oracle queue.

Unfortunately, when I create a jar of this class file & run it, it just runs & then exits & consumes only 1 message in the queue. Why the listener not keep on running & listening to queue?

I thought it'll keep listening & retrieve all the messages in the queue & then will remain in listen mode forever, but its not behaving that way.

Appreciate if some one can tell me what's going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Try wrapping all of that code from the beginning of the try block to the end of the block with a while(true) so that once it consumes a message, it runs all of that queue setup again and is waiting for another message. I think you may have to create that session after you process each message since it's in main. This may not be the permanent solution, but it may get by for now.

Comment: @Logan, which try block are u referring to? Is it the one from main method?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The one in the  main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how another JMS example loops to process multiple messages.

```
Performs a JNDI lookup of the ConnectionFactory and Destination.
Creates a Connection and a Session.
Creates a MessageConsumer:

consumer = session.createConsumer(dest);
Starts the connection, causing message delivery to begin:

connection.start();
Receives the messages sent to the destination until the end-of-message-stream control message is received:

while (true) {
  Message m = consumer.receive(1);
  if (m != null) {
    if (m instanceof TextMessage) {
      message = (TextMessage) m;
      System.out.println("Reading message: " +
        message.getText());
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}

Because the control message is not a TextMessage, the receiving program terminates the while loop and stops receiving messages after the control message arrives.
Closes the connection in a finally block, automatically closing the session and MessageConsumer.
```

You may be able to get away with just wrapping this code in the while loop. It depends on how JMS makes you handle the connection and session objects and if they automatically close, but you can try to wrap just this.

```
while(true) {
       QCon.start();

       queue = ((AQjmsSession) session).getQueue(queueUserName, queueName);
       MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);       

       consumer.setMessageListener(a);
       QCon.setExceptionListener(a);

       consumer.close();
}
```

Comment: I would put it before Queue queue and after your catch block in the main method, basically wrapping all of that code. Just to see if it runs more than once at first, then after that you can determine if any of that code can be pulled out and only executed once.

Comment: Will it take CPU if I put this while loop??? What will happen when there is no message in queue? Will it take CPU?

Comment: I don't think so. You can watch the process monitor to see if the process does anything, but this is pretty much what any process does. I think when you set your listener, the code waits for a message at that point, it doesn't actually finish the while loop. Your problem is that once a message comes in, it runs the rest of the code and closes. This loop should reset the listener so that once it processes it's ready for another.

Comment: I was able to retrieve all the messages in queue without using while loop. I just commented Consumer.close(), session.close() & Qcon.close() lines & it's now working. But again the question is whether its the correct way & how do I know how much memory is it taking?

Comment: There's a great tool to monitor any java process included in the java JKD. It's called jconsole. If you launch that while your program is running you can connect to your process and see how much memory it's using and cpu as it run.

Answer (score 2):

It's all because you're closing your connection/session immediately after starting up. YOu need the process to start off a daemon thread that runs forever in the JVM.  JMS is not responsible for keeping the JVM running.  You would need to create a thread that just slept to accomplish that.

Comment: Once a thread is created, when should it go to sleep? Can you please provide an example for my above code?